# Can MS Projects be integrated in SharePoint?

Tags: ms-project, tools

I wonder if it's possible to integrate a template from MS Projects into SharePoint.

We have been using this tool to plan and illustrate workpackages. However, since we have moved into a bigger team in remote locations we have been asked by management to find a way to incorporate our plans into SharePoint.

SharePoint has become the online workspace in our department, but I am not sure how efficient it is to track progress.

Any thoughts on how to do this effectively?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I believe what you might be looking for is [MS Office Project Server](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Office_Project_Server) which allows to publish project plan as a baseline and then actively update progress through the web, e.g. you don't need MS Project installed on every machine you want to make updates from.

Actually the new version works basing on SharePoint. Older ones worked as stand alone solutions, but you could still achieve the same effect.

Comment: The answer is yes, using project server (as @pawekbrodzinski notes), but I can tell you from painful experience that you will rue the day you were born when you try to implement it. Permissions problems galore. Really, really, look at your requirements hard before you head down that route.

Answer (score 4):

In SharePoint 2010 there is a list template called "Project Tasks List". This will then easily synchronise with you MPP file.

But be careful - if you customise your list, not all data types synchronise with MPP properly.

Answer (score 3):

Project Server is expensive to maintain with a huge learning curve.  As an aerospace PM with the help of a team, we reviewed several PMIS options and found MSPS far outside our requirements.

Currently we're reviewing MS Project 2010 as an option to integrate with Sharepoint which we highly use to collaborate with our project team.  We currently use MS Project 2007 to share PDFs and what-if MS Project 2007 files only.  The original/officially maintained MSP07 file is stored on a server location.  Our PMs access the latest what-if file to status, make what-ifs, propose customer approved baseline changes, etc.

Suggest reviewing MS Project 2010.

Answer (score 2):

If you cannot deploy Project Server there is nothing to to stop you from using a regular SharePoint site to host the MPP file. The SharePoint site will simply act as a web-enabled file sharing system and will treat that file just like it would any other file (check-in, check-out, version history, etc.)